# DLL and fully-specialized template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, linker

Environment: Visual Studio 9, C++ without managed extensions.

I've got a third-party library which exports a fully-specialized template class `MyClass<42>` defined in MyClass.h. It gets compiled into a helper loader .lib and a .dll file. The .lib file contains compiled code for this specialization, and necessary symbols. The MyClass.h looks like this:

```
template<UInt D>
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {...};
    virtual ~MyClass() {};
}
```

Now I'd like to use this library. If I include the MyClass.h in a Client.cpp and then compile it, I'll get second copy of these symbols in the Client.obj file. I can get rid of these symbols by defining all the member of that specialization as "extern". My Client.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <ThirdParty/MyClass.h>

extern template class MyClass<42>;
extern template MyClass<42>::MyClass<42>();
extern template MyClass<42>::~MyClass<42>();

void MyFunction(MyClass<42>& obj) {...}
```

The problem is that I cannot get rid of the virtual destructor this way. For the virtual destructor I get an almost standard LNK2005 error:

```
ThirdPartyd.lib(ThirdPartyd.dll) : error LNK2005:
    "public: virtual __thiscall MyClass<42>::~MyClass<42>(void)"
    (??1?$MyClass@$01@@@UAE@XZ) already defined in Client.obj
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that for virtual methods it is necessary to define them as both `extern` and `__declspec(dllimport)` at the same time:

```
extern template __declspec(dllimport) MyClass<42>::~MyClass<42>();
```

This made my linker happy enough to link my code properly.

I would be very glad if some expert described why is so, or at least pointed to some article explaining this case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Visual studio uses template specialization in dlls for some stl constructs. `string` comes to mind,

I had a quick look at the header file, and it looks like it's using

```
__declspec(dllimport)
```

on the declaration of a bunch of specializations. It does not seem that it does so for the whole class though.

From [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/1a30fef0-ffcc-464c-94e3-44239c0a84c5) it sounds like it is possible to declare the whole class as exported, but does not say how.

Sorry for the not-so-complete answer, but hopefully, this can help you explore other venues.