# Windows & C++: extern & __declspec(dllimport)

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker

What is the difference/relationship between `extern` and `__declspec(dllimport)`? I found that sometimes it is necessary to use both of them, sometimes one is enough.

Am I right that:

1. `extern` is for statically linked libraries,
2. `__declspec(dllimport)` is for DLL (dynamically linked libraries),
3. both do actually the same job for their respective type of linking,
4. you need to use both when you use import libraries (small .lib files that help linking with dll)?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`extern` means that the entity has external linkage, i.e. is visible outside its translation unit (C or CPP file). The implication of this is that a corresponding symbol will be placed in the object file, and it will hence also be visible if this object file is made part of a static library. However, `extern` does not by itself imply that the symbol will also be visible once the object file is made part of a DLL.

`__declspec(dllexport)` means that the symbol should be exported from a DLL (if it is indeed made part of a DLL). It is used when compiling the code that goes into the DLL.

`__declspec(dllimport)` means that the symbol will be imported from a DLL. It is used when compiling the code that uses the DLL.

Because the same header file is usually used both when compiling the DLL itself as well as the client code that will use the DLL, it is customary to define a macro that resolves to `__declspec(dllexport)` when compiling the DLL and `__declspec(dllimport)` when compiling its client, like so:

```
#if COMPILING_THE_DLL
    #define DLLEXTERN __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLLEXTERN __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes, `extern` alone is sufficient for static libraries.
2. Yes -- and the declaration also needs an `extern` ([see explanation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4h7bcy6%28VS.80%29.aspx)).
3. Not quite -- see above.
4. You don't strictly need the `extern` with a `__declspec(dllimport)` (see explanation linked to above), but since you'll usually be using the same header file, you'll already have the `extern` in there because it's needed when compiling the DLL.

Comment: Ad 4.: What with virtual inline methods? AFAIK they need `extern`; this is actually what I found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284648/dll-and-fully-specialized-template-class

Comment: For classes, the most manageable (and usual) approach is to declare the entire class `__declspec(dllexport)`. Exporting individual class members is more complicated... see for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c%28VS.80%29.aspx.

Comment: The MSVS 2005 documentation is retired and the '(see explanation here)' link goes to some of the retired documentation.  Is there a chance of getting the link updated to its equivalent in a more recent version of MSVS?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler archive.org tells me it's the older version of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/definitions-and-declarations-cpp?view=vs-2019

Comment: @PeterT — Thanks!